# How to filter where in multiple columns simultaneously in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a table `entities` with `name` and `entity_type` columns, and want to lookup multiple rows testing for pairs of both these columns. In plain SQL, I can do this with:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM entities
WHERE (name, entity_type) IN (('abc', 'type1'), ('def', 'type2'))
```

In SQLAlchemy ORM it's simple to filter WHERE IN a single list like:

```python
session.query(Entity).filter(User.name.in_(['abc', 'def']))
```

Is there an efficient SQLAlchemy equivalent of the top SQL expression? I don't think it's especially relevant, but for the record I'm interested in running this against PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this, you can use this with some variables name change:

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_

   session.query(Ent).filter(tuple_(Ent.name, Ent.type).in_(items))
```

notes:

> 1.Item must be list of tuples
>
> 2.This works with PostgreSQL, but breaks with SQLite.

If you are not allow to use `tuple_` there is another way. let me know, I will update my answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you know if there's an accepted term for this type of SQL expression? I note it's been flagged as a duplicate, but I (and apparently the last person to ask!) didn't know what to call this.

Comment: For the record, it doesn't seem the reason this fails to work in SQLite is due to a SQLAlchemy limitation but because SQLite cannot run the query (you get `row value misused`).